# Not able to remove option in cloned select

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have an issue with removing a cloned `option` that I created. I can remove the original option, but nothing is removed from the clone.

```js
var oriFruit = $('option', '#fruit').clone();
$("#fruit").find("[value='fruit1']").remove(); // works

console.log(oriFruit.length); // = 4
oriFruit.find("option[value='fruit1']").remove(); // does not work
console.log(oriFruit.length); // = 4, I expect 3
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<select id="fruit" multiple="multiple" class="form-control">
  <option value="fruit1">fruit1</option>
  <option value="fruit2">fruit2</option>
  <option value="fruit3">fruit3</option>
  <option value="fruit4">fruit4</option>
</select>
```

What is wrong with this code? I tried several methods but still failed. Thanks for helping me.

Comment: this element is missing : `$('option','#fruit')` so nothing is copied

Comment: @johnSmith that selector is fine, although a little hard to read. It's using the context selector so is equivalent to `$('#fruit').find('option')`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue is because you're selecting the `option` elements. As such there is no root node in the jQuery object to `remove()` the `option` elements from. Trying to `find()` instead of `filter()` that collection is another issue, but not the main problem.

To fix this, `clone()` the entire `select` element and then `find()` and `remove()` the target `option`. Try this:

```js
var oriFruit = $('#fruit').clone();
$("#fruit").find("[value='fruit1']").remove();

console.log(oriFruit.children().length); // = 4
oriFruit.find("option[value='fruit1']").remove();
console.log(oriFruit.children().length); // = 3

$('body').append(oriFruit);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<select id="fruit" multiple="multiple" class="form-control">
  <option value="fruit1">fruit1</option>
  <option value="fruit2">fruit2</option>
  <option value="fruit3">fruit3</option>
  <option value="fruit4">fruit4</option>
</select>

Clone:
```

Comment: Hi Rori, Thanks for the answer! This is exactly im looking for. Learn new thing today no root node and using children.

Comment: No problem, glad to help